# Nao Kinect Hydro

Tags: kinect, openni, skeleton-tracker, ros-hydro, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i have been working with the tutorial of Nao + Kinect in order to move the nao with the kinect.
That tutorial its made for Fuerte, and im trying to use it with Hydro but there are many dependencies that have been changed, like Joy/ has change for Joystick remmaper, and the openni libraries have been modified as well.
Is there any way to use that tutorial or any other, to move the nao with the kinect using hydro?
Or any other way to make the nao follow the kinect skeleton tracker?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142631/nao-kinect-hydro/) by [jcjc1](https://answers.ros.org/users/5187/jcjc1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of course there is a way: Start porting the tutorial to hydro.

The community will reward you.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0